# React.RefObject combined with Material-UI RootRef null, in a typescript class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I need a [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) link to a component.

So, normally an easy common way to use.

I need this on a Material-Ui component, so I decided to rebuild this [example](https://material-ui.com/api/root-ref/).

```js
import React, {
  Component,
  RefObject
} from "react";
import { RootRef, Popover } from "@material-ui/core";

class Home extends Component {
  private PopoverRef: React.RefObject < {} > ;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.PopoverRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.PopoverRef.current); // Allways null
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
    <RootRef rootRef = {this.PopoverRef} >
      <Popover props.../> 
    </RootRef>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that `this.PopoverRef.current` is always null.